# How to resolve the ambiguity in the function passed to boost thread

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to create a new thread using boost ,  the function RenderOut is a member of the class BlueOut.

the function is overloaded and how do i resolve this ambiguity while passing itto the boost thread.

```
void BlueOut::RenderOut( int i);
void BlueOut::RenderOut( std::string str);

BlueOut blueout;
boost::thread* thr = new boost::thread(boost::bind ( &BlueOut::RenderOut , &blueout ));
```

Comment: I think adding parameter should do the trick `boost::thread* thr = new boost::thread(boost::bind ( &BlueOut::RenderOut , &blueout, somestring ))`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @RC0993 yes i tried but not working , still showing ambiguity error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a member function from an overload set, cast the member function pointer to the desired type. So to select the `int` version, use this:

```
static_cast<void (BlueOut::*)(int)>(&BlueOut::RenderOut);
```

To select the `std::string` version, use this:

```
static_cast<void (BlueOut::*)(std::string)>(&BlueOut::RenderOut);
```

Using this in your example, you'd write this:

```
// you didn't specify which overload you wanted so I chose `int` because I have no idea
boost::thread* thr = new boost::thread(
  boost::bind(
    static_cast<void (BlueOut::*)(int)>(&BlueOut::RenderOut), 
    &blueout
  )
);
```

---

The same principle works for free functions and static functions too. Given these functions:

```
void RenderOut(int);
void RenderOut(std::string);
```

You can select the `int` version with this:

```
static_cast<void(*)(int)>(&RenderOut);
```

...and select the `std::string` version with this:

```
static_cast<void(*)(std::string)>(&RenderOut);
```

You can read more about this on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address).